# WordPress plugin for media library

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a WP plugin that:

1. adds media from files in a folder on the server filesystem and all of its subfolders
2. automatically creates categories for media that it added that way, where the categories names match the folders names and the categories hierarchy matches the folders hierarchy

The ["Add From Server"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) plugin does step 1 while the PRO version of ["Enhanced Media Library"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/) might enable me to manually do something similar to step 2, but it's not quite the same thing.

I need a plugin that does both in a single step because I suspect the categories hierarchy needs to be built while uploading media and a plugin that builds it afterwards but does not allow to add media from a folder on the server is unlikely to be of much use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a structure of how the directory and images would look and how you would want the folder names would become categories for the images?

Comment: I have no fixed structure to show. Any directory name would be ok. A directory named "dir1" would become the category "dir1". Its subdirectory "dir2" would become a category "dir2" whose parent category would be "dir1", and so on. Images contained in the "dir2" directory would be put in the "dir2" category.

Comment: The second requirement is quite difficult to satisfy, but I hope someone knows a plugin that does it.